# Adding data from google my-places map to customized google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-places-api

I made a customized google map with javascript:
http://resortstudio.ch/kontakt/

I would like to directly add (import) many markers from a personal google-my-places-map.
From something similar to this example: http://goo.gl/maps/0uRg

In other words. I want to import the data from a saved, personal map on google-maps into my custom-styled map. Is there an easy way of importing those places/markers without having to write every location in code into my custom map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [KmlLayer in the google maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) to import KML. There is a [KML version of that map available](https://maps.google.ch/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=214148915556581732425.00048c8d7a85cb1291e7e) .

[Here is an example that displays the example you provided using the API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkto.html?filename=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.ch%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D214148915556581732425.00048c8d7a85cb1291e7e)

You asked:

> 1. Is there a way, to directly link to the KML-File on google maps
>      instead of download/put the KML file on a server by myself?

- The example above uses a link directly to the kml file stored on
  Google's servers.

> 2. When I load the KML-Layer, it ignores my defined "center" of the map. Same happens in your example above, where the "center" is set to Chicago, but is overwritten by the KML (NYC). Any way to overwrite the KML-center-setting?

- set the [preserveViewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) in the KmlLayerOptions.

---

You can download the KML mentioned above by clicking on the KML Link from your saved maps, see the image below and notice the last link (KML).

[image]

Comment: just added an edit to your answer to show the user where they can find the KML download of their map for future references

Comment: Unless I am confused, that was already there: https://maps.google.ch/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=214148915556581732425.00048c8d7a85cb1291e7e in any case, I don't think the OP provided a link to their map, just an example similar to what they wanted to use.

Comment: Looking closer, your example makes it clear how I got that link, which is an improvement, thank you, accepted the change.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you. 2 follow-up questions:

1. Is there a way, to directly link to the KML-File on google maps instead of download/put the KML file on a server by myself?

2. When I load the KML-Layer, it ignores my defined "center" of the map. Same happens in your example above, where the "center" is set to Chicago, but is overwritten by the KML (NYC). Any way to overwrite the KML-center-setting?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Addressed your additional questions.

Comment: Thank you! How did you get that direct link? When I try to get the KML link, I get a long, complicated link with numbers and stuff. Is the link in your example (stored on a google server) still connected to the "my places" map? So if I change a marker on the map it updates? That would be the idea.

Comment: The link to the kml on google's servers is a long complicated link, I found I needed to URL encode it when I passed it into that "linkto" example I provided (probably because it is being passed in the URL...).  It is still pointing to the current version of your "my places" map and will update if you add markers, but there will be caching delays (you may not see the change right away, but someone else will or if you go to a different computer you will.  There is caching at various places in the system (google's servers that render the kml cache it, your browser caches the tiles).